# Select Max(Date) and next highest Max(date) from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table with approx 100,000 rows per day, each containing the date they were added.  However, rows are only added on business days, so no weekends or bank holidays.

I'm trying to find an efficient way to find the `Max(BusinessDate)` and also the next highest `max(BusinessDate)`. However, when I try the following it takes 20 mins to run (+50Mn rows total).

```
SELECT
    MAX(t1.BusinessDataDate) AS BusinessDataDate
    , MAX(t2.BusinessDataDate) AS PreviousDataDate
FROM
    cb_account t1
    , cb_account t2
WHERE 
    t2.BusinessDataDate < t1.BusinessDataDate
```

Just selecting the `Max(BusinessDataDate)` is instant.

```
SELECT TOP 2
    'cb_account' AS TableName
    , BusinessDataDate
FROM cb_account
GROUP BY BusinessDataDate
ORDER BY BusinessDataDate DESC
```

will give me both the dates, but I really need them in a single row.

Comment: i am unabale to understand your question can you simplify it with raw sample data. as per my understanding you are asking for max date of your every day

Comment: Is there an **index** on your `BusinessDataDate` column? That would be extremely helpful ...

Comment: Yes, there is an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(dates.BusinessDataDate) AS BusinessDataDate, 
       MIN(dates.BusinessDataDate) AS PreviousDataDate
FROM
(SELECT TOP 2
    'cb_account' AS TableName
    , BusinessDataDate
FROM cb_account
GROUP BY BusinessDataDate
ORDER BY BusinessDataDate DESC) dates
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've got it right try this:

```
WITH T as 
(
  SELECT MAX(BusinessDataDate) as MaxD 
  FROM cb_account
)

SELECT MaxD, (SELECT MAX(BusinessDataDate) 
                    FROM cb_account 
                    WHERE BusinessDataDate<T.MaxD) 
FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the SQL version you are using ? if you are are on SQL 2012 you can use LEAD() or LAG() functions

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx